# SSL certification issue with Ubuntu on VMware

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssl, vmware-player

I have faced an issue and I couldn't solve it. I install Ubuntu (I tried any version between LTS14 to LTS18) and everything work fine except github website and git repo clone

If I treied to reach github.com on web browser I get Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER and if tried to get Project from git via terminal, I get fatal: error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)

I tried to change timezone and also I add new certificate from TrustCert site but non of them work for me.
I suspect my host and vm connection. I use NAT (default of Vmware) to share internet with VM and I think vmware using some virtual gateway, etc for this and I think git communication did not resolve of this communication. Is there anybody know this issue and solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you add the ssh key ?

Comment: yep check something around ssh key, on your VM it should be under ~/.ssh/<yourkey_rsa> and it must be -rw-------   (aka:600)

Comment: Yes I generate ssh key but there is nothing change. my host is Windows 10 and Linux installed on vmware. Is there any way to copy Windows ssh key to Linux vm? and is it really necessary?